# How can I submit multiple read queries to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

We have 3 or 4 Bson documents, which are similar read-queries, that we execute in separate Java threads and then combine the results in our Java application. We would like to change that approach and submit all of those at the same time to Mongo DB (version 6)

Researching that in Stack overflow, I see we can use a $facet query, which is not a bad solution, but it returns independent results.

I am wondering if there is a better solution for executing a set of related queries, and have MongoDB return a single result set with scoring?

Comment: What would be the pattern of the single queries? Maybe you can combine them into a single `$in` query at your api level?

Comment: Similarly perhaps `$or` would do the trick. Or `$unionWith`. Really difficult to advise without more specific information. `$facet` probably not the approach you're looking for with respect to performance though